# Delay in merging data Apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I am merging two Pcollections into one it takes up to 20 seconds for this merge. I check and calculations is fast and issue exactly on step of merge. I use 3 ways to implement this logic:

1. CoGroupByKey
2. Side input
3. Flatten

First 2 works with 20 sec delay.

And Flatten is not waiting when both Pcollections become not empty.

Is any way to combine several Pcollections in one without delay and allow them to compute in parallels?

The code is looks like this, I get data every minute. SMA5 count is fast and like should be.

```
def run(pipeline_options):
    pipeline_options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.StandardOptions).streaming = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with (beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p):
        data = (p
            | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
            | 'Convert from bstrings to dict' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
            | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(
                    window.FixedWindows(2),
                    # trigger=beam.transforms.trigger.AfterCount(1),
                    # accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING

                )
            )

        data_with_key = data | "Make key for data" >> beam.Map(lambda data: (data['timestamp'], data))
        sma5 = (data | 'CalculateSMA5' >> beam.ParDo(SMA5()))


        ((data_with_key, sma5) | 'CoGroupByKey' >> beam.CoGroupByKey() | 'get result  CoGroupByKey' >> beam.Map(print))
        data |"perfomring join">> beam.ParDo(cross_join, rights=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(sma5)) | "print side input" >> beam.Map(print) | "time2" >> beam.Map(lambda data: print(datetime.datetime.now()))
        (data_with_key, sma5) |"merge">> beam.Flatten() | "print flatten" >> beam.Map(print)
```

I have try different logic and want as result input data with new key, value pair.

Input:

data =  {'timestamp': 1696337640000, 'price': 1000}

SMA = (1696337640000, {'SMA_5': 995})

Output:
{'timestamp': 1696337640000, 'price': 1000, 'SMA_5': 995}

in future I will need a lot of different SMA and I want calculate them in parallels.
{'timestamp': 1696337640000, 'price': 1000, 'SMA_5': 995, ...}